# convert it to list flutter firebase

Tags: json, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[this is my database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUbNk.png)

```
import 'dart:convert';

class ReviewcountInfo{
  List<String> uid;

  ReviewcountInfo({
    required this.uid,
  })

  List<String> toList() {
    return
  }

  factory ReviewcountInfo.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return ReviewcountInfo(
      uid: ['uid'] ?? 0,
    );}
  String toJson() => json.encode(toList());

  factory ReviewcountInfo.fromJson(String source) =>
      ReviewcountInfo.fromMap(json.decode(source));

}
```

I want to get data in the form of an array from firebase, how can I get it?

I don't know how to fill 'List toList()','factory ReviewcountInfo' part.

```
class BrandingInfo {
  num price;
  BrandingInfo({
    required this.price,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'price': price,
    };
  }

  factory BrandingInfo.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return BrandingInfo(
      price: map['price'] ?? 0,
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory BrandingInfo.fromJson(String source) =>
      BrandingInfo.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```

this is my example Code

I am coding by referring to the code above.

Comment: you wanted to convert the firestore data to json to put on list?

Comment: Yes. I want to get the value of Firebase Array type.

Comment: can u include the image of data in firestore

Comment: upload my database image

Comment: Please don’t include links in questions. Include code as text and Firestore structures as a screenshot embedded in the question. Over time, links can break and if they do, future readers wont have access to that info which could invalidate the question.

Answer (score 0):

try this model

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<ReviewCount> reviewCountFromJson(String str) => List<ReviewCount>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => ReviewCount.fromJson(x)));

String reviewCountToJson(List<ReviewCount> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class ReviewCount {
    ReviewCount({
        this.reviewcount,
    });

    final Reviewcount? reviewcount;

    factory ReviewCount.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ReviewCount(
        reviewcount: json["reviewcount"] == null ? null : Reviewcount.fromJson(json["reviewcount"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "reviewcount": reviewcount == null ? null : reviewcount.toJson(),
    };
}

class Reviewcount {
    Reviewcount({
        this.uid,
    });

    final List<String>? uid;

    factory Reviewcount.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Reviewcount(
        uid: json["uid"] == null ? null : List<String>.from(json["uid"].map((x) => x)),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "uid": uid == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(uid!.map((x) => x)),
    };
}
```

then for getting the data from firestore

```
Future<Reviewcount> getuidList({String? pathDocuid}) async{
   
   final response = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("service").doc(pathDocuid!).get();
   final mapItFirst = response.data() as Map<String,dynamic>;
    
   // but first print the data using log so you can see if it 
   // gettingdata
   log("${mapItFirst['reviewcount']}");
   log("${mapItFirst['reviewcount']['uid']}");
   
   return Reviewcount.fromJson(mapItFirst["reviewcount"]);

 }
```

try this if it works if not mention me.